# Linking to an anchor on the same page

Tags: html

I want this link to simply scroll down the page without reloading:

```
<a href="#anchor">Link Text</a>
```

Should go to `<a id='anchor'/>` straight away.

However, it's reloading the page, and then going to the anchor tag. Why is this?

Shouldn't matter, but this is a Rails app.

Comment: Just tested on one of my rails apps and it seems to be working fine and not reloading, would there be any conflicting javascript or routes causing it to reload?

Comment: Link with an anchor like that will not reload the page as you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/wswnvqfg/ The problem lies somewhere else, can you provide more information and maybe markup?

Comment: `<a id='anchor'/>` is invalid HTML. The end tag for a elements is mandatory.

Comment: While `<a id='anchor'/>` is invalid HTML, it is valid XHTML and does work in this simple case https://jsfiddle.net/u94rut1k/1/

Comment: Are you using Angular?

Answer (score -2):

You should change the anchor tag to a div tag...It won't work with another anchor tag.

Have a look at how paralax websites are created but this should help with what you're looking for...

```
<a href="#divIdName">Go here</a>
<div id="divIdName">Destination</div>
```

Comment: Your comment is simply wrong, the anchor will work on any html-element, even another anchor with that id.

Comment: if my comment is wrong? Why does your suggested demo look exactly like what I demonstrated? and mine works too?

Comment: I didn't say your code was wrong or not working... My code was only to demonstrate that link with anchor does not reload the page. Your comment ***'it won't work with another anchor tag'*** is simply ***wrong and misleading*** and against html-specification.

Comment: You know...Knowledge is power...maybe you could've answered me in a better way to help me understand too! cheers

Answer (score -2):

Anchor in same page is like that :

```
<a href="#anyId">Anchor text</a>
<p id="anyId"></p>
```

Try it....

Answer (score -2):

Check if any event is bound on the anchor tag that you are using.